# Display XSL and PDF export along with the dropdown which allows us to select the number of rows to be displayed

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, datatable

I am using the following JavaScript code to draw the data table:

```
function drawDataTable(settings) {
    $('#' + settings.divid).html(
            "<table class='display' id='" + settings.tableid + "'></table>");
    dataTable_id = $('#' + settings.tableid).dataTable({
            "sDom" : '<"H"Tfr>t<"F"ip>',
                    "oTableTools" : {
                    "sSwfPath" : "../static/javascript/TableTools-2.1.4/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
                    "aButtons" : [{
                        "sButtonClass": "ui-image-btn",
                        "sExtends" : "xls",
                        "sButtonText" : "<img src='../static/images/excel.png' style='cursor: pointer;'/>"
                        },]
                    },
"bJQueryUI" : true,
        "iDisplayLength" : 5,
        "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
        "bFilter" : true,
        "bPaginate" : true,
        "bLengthChange" : true,
        "bProcessing" : true,
        "bSortable" : true,
        "sScrollXInner":true,
        "bInfo" : true,
        "bAutoWidth" : true,
        "fnServerData" : settings.fnServerData,
        "sAjaxSource" : settings.url,`enter code here`
        "fnRowCallback" : settings.fnRowCallback,
        "fnDrawCallback" : settings.fnDrawCallback,
        "aoColumns" : settings.columndef,
        "fnInitComplete": settings.fnCallback
});
    dataTable_id.removeAttr("style");
}
```

But I cannot see the option to choose the number of rows to be be displayed when the sDom for PDF and XSL export is working. How can I make both working. I need both option in the dataTable. Can anyone please help me.

I have searched in google. Some plugins are available. Is there any way by using these default data table.

Comment: why do you want to use js for this exports?? any special reason?

Comment: In the whole project we are following that structure. And this is a modification for existing working condition. We have to add the row selection in it without changing anything else

Comment: Got the Answer Give l in sDom ie  "sDom" : '<"H"Tlfr>t<"F"ip>',

Comment: because l stands for length

Comment: cool.. good keep it up.. yet I feel not to handle pdf export frm js ... for big data it would not generate as expected you may end up re-writing some lib of js... here i see a mix of client and server-side .. which is fine.. anyways, happy coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change sDom to "sDom" : '<"H"Tlfr>t<"F"ip>'